# C# Allow user to draw on winform with mouse/screen clicks

Tags: c#, graph, graphics, drawing

I am working on a personal project and I need to allow the client draw a "signature" on a new popup form, this by handling the events (maybe on-click and on-mouse over) events.

This signature has to be stored on an image object in order to save it to a varbinary(max) field on a database.

Googling around is not working, Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17895/handling-touch-pen-or-mouse-digitizer-input-in-you

Comment: Thank you for the comment @AbdelRaoof but it seems that the downloadable files for that specific post cannot be opened on VS2015. It also seems that the code is to be used with stylus. But the computers that are going to use the system do not have stylus and just have a touch screen.

Comment: How married are you to the idea of winforms?  You could do this out of the box in WPF with the InkCanvas control.  If you haven't already invested a lot of time into this project, it might be a good idea to switch to a GUI technology that's not quite so dated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked in my touch screen laptop, touchdown event can be handled through **MouseDown** event, touchup through **MouseUp** and touchmove through **MouseMove** event of the form.

**Note:** My machine has both touch and mouse support. I am not sure about touch only devices or machines.

Following code allows you to draw on the form through touch/mouse interactions.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Image signature;
    bool clicked = false;
    Point previousPoint;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        this.MouseDown += Form1_MouseDown;
        this.MouseUp += Form1_MouseUp;
        this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
        this.MouseLeave += Form1_MouseLeave;

        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Dispose signature after closing the form to avoid memory leak
        signature.Dispose();
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (signature != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(signature, 0, 0);
    }

    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicked = true;
        previousPoint = e.Location;
    }

    void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clicked = false;
    }

    void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicked = false;
    }

    void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clicked)
        {
            if (signature == null)
                signature = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(signature))
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, previousPoint, e.Location);
                previousPoint = e.Location;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The signature is drawn on an image. So you can save the image as required in your database.

Comment: thank you for your response.

Now I am having problems with the assignment of the created image on a picture box on a different form... I am doing this:

1. Change the signature on the form2 to a property.
2. Open the form2 as a Dialogresult form.
3. Store the result of the dialogresult and return it with a button on the form2
4. Assign the value from form2.signature on the form1.picturebox

The error is the following: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.**

Comment: Maybe you are assigning a disposed image. In my code, the image is disposed in FormClosing event. If you need the image after closing, you can remove the line signature.Dispose(). But make sure, image is disposed after use.

Comment: That was the problem... Thank you once again @kira but now how can I dispose the signature after the form has closed?

Comment: if it is a property of form2, we can dispose it like form2.Signature.Dispose(); form2.Signature = null; I'm assigning null after disposing to avoid drawing on the disposed image

Comment: Great, thank you @kira

Comment: The solution from @kira was successful for me.